# Python command to run on every 45th second

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i make the the program run every time the timestamp in seconds is 45, currently I am using time.sleep, but my run time tends to vary a little bit every time the program is executed and i would like it to execute again if the timestamp is on the 45th second. Currently I have something like this where the run loop commences every 60 seconds, however I would like it to run the loop when the timestamp seconds slot == 45

```
def run_loop(self):
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("-----\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        start = time.time()
        self.takeProfit()
        self.place_orders()
        end = time.time()
        print("runtime is ", end - start)
        sleep(60)
def run():
    # Try/except just keeps ctrl-c from printing an ugly stacktrace
    ei = ExchangeInterface()
    try:
        ei.run_loop()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.exit()

ExchangeInterface.run()
```

My run time at the moment tends to be around 18-20 seconds

Comment: I'd recommend posting your current working code, with specifics about what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: [`sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', minutes=1, start_date='2018-12-5 00:00:45')`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.interval), perhaps?

Comment: Simple: `time.sleep(45 - runtime)`; more accurate: calculate the next 45s interval end and sleep for the difference to that point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `datetime` module, and check if `datetime.now().second == 45`.

E.g.

```
from datetime import datetime

if datetime.now().second == 45:
    do_stuff()
```

In your case you would use some logic to check every X amount of time if we are at the 45th second.

Comment: My runtime is 18-20 seconds, so this worked perfect for me. Thank You!!

Comment: @mypetlion I'd avoid putting this check in a `while True` loop, if that's what you're thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you specifically mean run an event at the 45-th second of the minute?

That sounds like you want to do event scheduling:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

In the example on that page, they only use the `enter` method of the scheduler and not `enterabs`, which is what you should be using.

For that, you need to figure out the time that's at 45 seconds from the current minute. Some simple math gives that:

```
t = time.time()
minute = 60 * (t \\ 60) #Use integer division!
s.enterabs(minute + 45, ...)
s.run()
```

The stuff inside the `...` specifies what you want to run/schedule, just read up on the package doc to figure out the format.

Then just put that scheduling into your loop and it should all be good, and no need for the `sleep(60)` no more.